# Maximizing window size of site from java selenium- web driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How can I maximize window size of site that I opened from Java selenium- webdriver?

Comment: `driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Comment: Thank you very much Kun Lun! It does answer my question.

Comment: Using `org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions`  you can start Chrome maximized. `import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the window as per the required dimension.

Dimension d = new Dimension(800,480);
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);